# Why does Smart UV Project create so many faces?

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image]
As you can see on the image, Smart UV creates too many faces and this just looks cheap and dirty.

[image]

How do I make it look like this in Blender?

Comment: you could add seams and use normal unwrap

Comment: I added Mark Seams and pressed Unwrap, but It looks more terrible than before.

Comment: could you add a picture of the seams?

Comment: Sure, I added it.

Comment: you only add seams to places where you would cut your mesh with a scissor to fold it out like you would in real life

Comment: You literally made *every* edge a seam. No wonder you result gets horrible. Remove all seams and retry the Smart UV

Comment: for example added seams and unwrap result below: http://imgur.com/gallery/AFzlb

Comment: Thanks for share the link. I saw that, and I'm trying. It's getting closer time to time but still this is very confused for me :/

Comment: *It's very confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

you only add seams to places where you would cut your mesh with a scissor to fold it out like you would in real life,

As an example I added seams and unwrapped. Black line that I have drawn on the icosphere shows how it will be unwrapped:

[image]